# Why does vscode change directories before running a python file?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a file in `c:\github\housing\python` called sync.py. While it is open in my VS Code browser, I hit Ctrl F5 to execute it. When I do that, this is what I see in PowerShell:

```
PS C:\github\housing\python> cd 'c:\github\twitter'; & 'C:\Users\azhad\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'c:\Users\azhad\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.114305\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '52870' '--' 'c:\github\housing\python\sync.py'
```

why is VS Code changing to a different directory? I have noticed that it seems to gravitate towards the twitter folder, is there a default setting I can change to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when the python file is executed in the terminal "`powershell`" in VSCode, it will change the path in two places:

1. `"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,` is set in "`settings.json`".
2. `"cwd": "c:\\github\\twitter"` is set in "`launch.json`":

   [image]

It is recommended that you comment out the relevant terminal debugging settings in the two setting files "`settings.json`" and "`launch.json`". In addition, please try to reload or reopen VSCode.